# Automation scripts Failure only at working hours

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testing, automation

Automation scripts are running well and good after our manual teams work time as automation scripts also are running on the same environment.
Do working in the same environment can cause click interception or stale exception errors due to slowness as well ?

Because the scripts are running fine late evening or night
Even I have given fix for stale exception and click interception in few areas where the error has popes up but again the next day it would show error in some other actions performing.

Comment: Yes.  In general seemingly random type errors often indicate timing issues.  To resolve this you may want to increase timeout periods.  (for more specific advice show code for click intercepted and stale element remedies)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.